# Does every non-compact bounded metric space support an equivalent metric in which it is unbounded?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider $X$ be an infinite set. Let $d$ be a non compact bounded metric on $X$. Can we define an unbounded metric $d'$ on $X$ such that both the metric spaces $(X,d)$ and $(X,d')$ give the same topology?

<sup>(Since compact metric spaces are   bounded, the assumption that $X$ is not compact is necessary)</sup>

Comment: Not if $X$ is compact.

Comment: Yes. You are right Lee Mosher. Now I have changed the problem.

Comment: The metric $d(x,y)=\min\{1,|y-x|\}$ gives a topology on $\mathbb{R}$ which is homeomorphic to the usual topology.

Comment: That is true. But I was asking the existence in general @ Daniel Rust

Comment: Partial answer: if $X$ is not complete, consider its completion $\overline{X}$ and fix a point $p\in\overline{X}\setminus X$. There is an equivalent metric on $X$ that is comparable (within the factor of $4$) to $d(x,y)/[d(x,p)d(y,p)]$. In many cases, this metric is unbounded near $p$. This is known as [inversion of a metric space](http://www.math.vt.edu/people/xiexg/bhx.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

This follows from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/58864/4280): a metrisable space is compact iff every compatible metric is bounded.

The proof in particular shows that if $(X,d)$ is non-compact, there is an equivalent metric $d'$ such that $(X,d')$ is unbounded and the construction is pretty explicit.